# How to make R code with an array to be more efficient?

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a following R code which is not efficient. I would like to make this efficient using Rcpp. Particularly, I am not used to dealing with array in Rcpp. Any help would be appreciated.

```
myfunc <- function(n=1600,
                   m=400,
                   p = 3,
                   time = runif(n,min=0.05,max=4),
                   qi21 = rnorm(n),
                   s0c = rnorm(n),
                   zc_min_ecox_multi = array(rnorm(n*n*p),dim=c(n,n,p)),
                   qi=matrix(0,n,n),
                   qi11 = rnorm(p),
                   iIc_mat = matrix(rnorm(p*p),p,p)){

            for (j in 1:n){
              u<-time[j]
              ind<-1*(u<=time)
              locu<-which(time==u)
              qi2<- sum(qi21*ind) /s0c[locu]

              for (i in 1:n){
                qi1<-  qi11%*%iIc_mat%*%matrix(zc_min_ecox_multi[i,j,],p,1)
                qi[i,j]<- -(qi1+qi2)/m

              }
            }

}
```

Computing time is about 7.35 secs. I need to call this function over and over again, maybe 20 times.

```
system.time(myfunc())
   user  system elapsed 
   7.34    0.00    7.35
```

Comment: isn't `locu` just equivalent to `j`?  I would avoid using `==` with floats in any case

Comment: @ pickle rick Yes you are right. With that change, computing time is still the same in R.

Comment: You're looping over n * n elements, which can be a lot. This is known to be slow in interpreted languages. Try to vectorize at least one of the 2 loops.

Comment: BTW, most people answering here are R enthusiasts. Saying "R is bad" in your question won't help you having people help you.

Comment: @ F. Prive Sorry didn't know that. Anyway I have edited my question title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing to do would be to profile your code: `profvis::profvis({myfunc()})`.

What you can do is precompute `qi11 %*% iIc_mat` once.
You get (with minor improvements):

```
precomp <- qi11 %*% iIc_mat

for (j in 1:n) {
  u <- time[j]
  qi2 <- sum(qi21[u <= time]) / s0c[time == u]

  for (i in 1:n) {
    qi1 <- precomp %*% zc_min_ecox_multi[i, j, ]
    qi[i, j] <- -(qi1 + qi2) / m
  }
}
```

that is twice as fast (8 sec -> 4 sec).

Vectorizing the `i` loop then seems straightforward:

```
q1_all_i <- tcrossprod(precomp, zc_min_ecox_multi[, j, ])
qi[, j] <- -(q1_all_i + qi2) / m
```

(12 times as fast now)

Comment: @ F. Prive Wow and thank you. That is a big improvement. I am not able to get same qi matrix using the original code and your code.

Comment: @ F. Prive Nevermind. It is the same. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ F. Prive I have another question related to vectorizing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936849/efficient-way-to-vectorize-r-for-loops.

Comment: Prive I just realized that the qi2 is just a scalar where you vectorize the i loop. Because i am getting the warning as follows: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

Comment: Yes. Your original code `qi[i,j]<- -(qi1+qi2)/m` implies that it is a scalar, right?

Comment: Yes -(qi_1+qi_2)/m is a scalar. But q1_all_i is not a scalar and qi2 is a scalar on the part where you vectorize the i loop. Do we need to vectorize qi2 as well. I would assume it should not matter. I am not getting an error but rather getting a warning.

Comment: I know what's going on. My time vector has repeated values and that is why I am getting the warning. I think it's okay and I will handle that.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to try it in Rcpp, you will first need a function to multiply the matrices...

```cpp
#include<Rcpp.h>
#include<numeric>
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]


Rcpp::NumericMatrix mult(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& lhs,
                         const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& rhs)
{
  if (lhs.ncol() != rhs.nrow())
    Rcpp::stop ("Incompatible matrices");
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix out(lhs.nrow(),rhs.ncol());
  Rcpp::NumericVector rowvec, colvec;
  for (int i = 0; i < lhs.nrow(); ++i)
    {
      rowvec = lhs(i,Rcpp::_);
      for (int j = 0; j < rhs.ncol(); ++j)
      {
        colvec = rhs(Rcpp::_,j);
        out(i, j) = std::inner_product(rowvec.begin(), rowvec.end(),
                                      colvec.begin(), 0.);
      }
    }
  return out;
}
```

Then port your function...

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix myfunc_rcpp( int n, int m, int p,
                                 const Rcpp::NumericVector& time,
                                 const Rcpp::NumericVector& qi21,
                                 const Rcpp::NumericVector& s0c,
                                 const Rcpp::NumericVector& zc_min_ecox_multi,
                                 const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& qi11,
                                 const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& iIc_mat)
{
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix qi(n, n);
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix outermat = mult(qi11, iIc_mat);

  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
  {
    double qi2 = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
    {
      if(time[j] <= time[k]) qi2 += qi21[k];
    }
    qi2 /= s0c[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      Rcpp::NumericMatrix tmpmat(p, 1);
      for(int z = 0; z < p; ++z)
      {
        tmpmat(z, 0) =  zc_min_ecox_multi[i + n*j + z*n*n];
      }
      Rcpp::NumericMatrix qi1 =  mult(outermat, tmpmat);
      qi(i,j) -= (qi1(0,0) + qi2)/m;
    }
  }
  return qi;
}
```

Then in R:

```r
my_rcpp_func <- function(n=1600,
                   m=400,
                   p = 3,
                   time = runif(n,min=0.05,max=4),
                   qi21 = rnorm(n),
                   s0c = rnorm(n),
                   zc_min_ecox_multi = array(rnorm(n*n*p),dim=c(n,n,p)),
                   qi11 = rnorm(p),
                   iIc_mat = matrix(rnorm(p*p),p,p))
{
  myfunc_rcpp(n, m, p, time, qi21, s0c, as.vector(zc_min_ecox_multi),
              matrix(qi11,1,p), iIc_mat)
}
```

This is certainly faster, and gives the same results as your own function, but it's no quicker than the in-R optimizations suggested by F Privé. Maybe optimizing the C++ code could get things even faster, but ultimately you are multiplying 2 reasonably large matrices together over 2.5 million times, so it's never going to be all that fast. R is optimized pretty well for this kind of calculation after all...

Comment: @ Allan Cameron Thanks for trying in Rcpp. I compared the computing time and there is not much difference.

Comment: @ Allan Cameron I thought there is already a way to multiply matrices in Rcpp. May I ask why you created function mult in Rcpp?

Comment: @Hello I don't think there is a direct way to multiply matrices in Rcpp, though you can do it with RcppArmadillo

Comment: @ Allan Cameron Okay.

Comment: @ Allan Cameron Actually the result obtained using R code(suggested by F Prive) and your function does not match.

Comment: @Hello The Rcpp code gives the same output as your original function. If you run set.seed(1) and save your output, then set.seed(1) and save the rcpp output, they match exactly. I haven't tried F Prive's function.

Comment: @ Allan Cameron I tried my original code, F Prive's code and your code. My original code and F. Prive's produce exactly same result. However, we have a different result than yours.

Comment: @ Allan Cameron In the for loop for z, could you please explain how the indexing is done for an array? I understand that array is treated as a long vector.

Comment: Correct @Hello - there is no numeric array in rcpp. It is a single long vector with a dimensions attribute (actually, this is how it works internally in R too), so you need to specify the exact position in the vector. There are n cells in every column, and n columns in every layer, so the index [i,j,z] is accessed by skipping z x n x n (cells in z full layers) +  j x n (full columns) + i (single cells in the current column).

Comment: @Hello that made me realise my indexing was wrong - now changed.

Comment: @ Allan Cameron Exactly. Thanks.